# Vue Router - Dynamic segments based on a fixed list

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

[Dynamic segments](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching) in Vue Router start with a colon:

```js
{ path: '/user/:username', component: User }
```

But what if I want to match only a set of names like: Bob, John, Jane, Chris.
I'd like to configure something like:

```js
{ path: '/user/:username(\\Bob|John|Jane|Chris)', component: User }
```

I tried to accomplish this with the built-in [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) path matching engine but without any luck.

Comment: It makes more sense to do this check inside route hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is incorrectly prefixed with `\\` (perhaps you thought an escape sequence was necessary).

Remove it to resolve the issue:

```js
//{ path: '/user/:username(\\Bob|John|Jane|Chris)', component: User } ❌
                           ^^

{ path: '/user/:username(Bob|John|Jane|Chris)', component: User } ✅
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-segments-in-vue-router-e5ike?file=/src/router.js:322-343)